# How do I find the percentage between two columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, percentage

Two parameters in my SELECT statement are:

```
count(product_code.code) as codes_allocated
count(case when product_code.taken='TRUE' then product_code.taken end) as codes_claimed
```

I would like to add one more parameter to my select statement that takes the codes_claimed and divides it by the codes_allocated to get a percentage of the codes claimed.

I've tried many things but always get the error:

> ERROR:  division by zero
>
> Query failed.

My most recent attempt used the following:

```
(count(case when core_isvcode.reserved='TRUE' then core_isvcode.reserved end)::decimal / count(core_isvcode.code)::decimal)*100 as Percent_redeemed`
```

Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what cases can `codes_allocated` be 0? Perhaps you should filter out rows where `codes_allocated` is 0.

Comment: When a new product is added, or when codes are transported over to another system, the count can drop to zero. A good idea but one I'm not to certain how to tackle yet. Will do some digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not include a `CASE` to validate `count(core_isvcode.code) > 0`

```
CASE WHEN count(core_isvcode.code) > 0 THEN
   (count(case when core_isvcode.reserved='TRUE' then core_isvcode.reserved end)::decimal 
   / count(core_isvcode.code)::decimal)*100 
  ELSE NULL 
END as Percent_redeemed
```

Comment: This also worked and added the least amount of time to complete the query, thanks you all for the help. Just to make sure I understand what this is doing...it basically says if the count is greater than 0, then divide the reserved code count by the total code count. Otherwise, the value is null (it won't divide numbers?

Comment: @Jacktheyeti Correct, I include the `ELSE` part for clarity but that is the default return  value you could remove it and would be exact the same

Answer (score 0):

I think `nullif()` is often the simplest method:

```
(count(case when core_isvcode.reserved='TRUE' then core_isvcode.reserved end)::decimal / nullif(count(core_isvcode.code)::decimal))*100 as Percent_redeemed
```

However, I think `avg()` is simpler for this calculation:

```
avg(case when core_isvcode.reserved = 'TRUE' then 100.0
         when core_isvcode.reserved is null then NULL
         else 0.0
    end)
```

Comment: Using the avg() function worked successfully. However it added a little more time to complete the query.

Comment: @Jacktheyeti . . . That is surprising.  How much more time?

Comment: ~2. It could be the nature of my complete query. I have a rather large query with multiple joins and calculations not shown here

Comment: @Jacktheyeti . . . I would expect the execution time to be indistinguishable from doing an explicit division.  There might be a few computer instructions of benefit, one way or the other, but it is hard to tell which would be negligibly faster or slower.

Comment: I am probably incorrect in saying that it added a little more time to the query. I apologize. I just noted the time it took to complete the query based on the time noted in my sql client.